# Add schema to each query in Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework, schema, entity-framework-6

Firstly, I am new to EF but am an experienced NHibernate user...

I am trying to update an existing EF repository layer that is talking to an existing database to automatically include a schema in every query submitted to the the database. To clarify:

- The database tables already exist, but they have been moved to a new schema in SQL Server
- The C# class model already exists

The database isn't created each time as is already exists, so the OnModelCreating method of the DbContext is never called. The classes have [Key] etc. from the DataAnnotations namespace, so I'm guessing it's code first.

In NHibernate, this is easy as I can add a default schema when building the configuration, so that every query automatically has the schema added to it regardless of the existing class model - the database and class model don't need to be updated.

Is this possible in Entity Framework and if so, where would I put this override? If not, how can I change EF to inject a schema to each query? Can I override the query generation function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your DbContext add the following

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("myNewSchema");
}
```

if there is no schema defined elsewhere this will take care of it globally.  I think that an explicitly defined schema elsewhere will override the default schema you set here.

Comment: Well, this is what I thought... but this method is not called in my  app when it runs. When is this method meant to run? Each time the dbcontext is instantiated?

Comment: It's part of the initialization process, so it should only run once in a given app domain.  It's part of the reason why the first query in code first is so much slower than all of the other ones.  Are you inheriting directly from DbContext?  Can you throw a System.Diagnotics.Debugger.Launch(); in that method and then write a unit test with a simple query in it.